# With MAUI projet if in adroidmanifest i have 'android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification"' where i put my image?

Tags: android, image, maui

in a MAUI projet if in adroidmanifest i have:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

where i must put my image ?

best regards

Answer (score 3):

Under `Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable` that is the Android native resources folder

Comment: ok, but on maui this folder doesn't exist ! Is it necessary to create it ? I am not sure ?

Comment: @sly Yes, you can create it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a folder name drawable in plateforme\android\resources. You put an image with build action to MauiImage.

it is not necessary to add in android manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

Add in the mainactivity

```
FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.your_icon;
```

and it works for me perfectly